# Numeric keyboard keep open but disable all buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

We have a certain program where user type numbers on numeric keyboard, but also buttons on its `accessible view` . So if he typed a specific button on the view I want to **keep the keyboard open but disable it**, while the accessible view still open and works.

So for example if he typed "A" on the view , I want to disable the numeric keyboard **while its still open**, till he type "C" and it will be enabled again.

I couldn't find a way to disable it and keep it open.

Comment: You can implement the text fields delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and return `false` when you don't want to accept input from keyboard. The keyboard will remain clickable, but the input will/wont't get propagated based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks very much, I know this trick I wanted to create a beautiful user experience when there is no room for mistakes. I will go with that if I have no choice.

Comment: The only other way would be to create your own custom keyboard and program it to achieve your results. For instance, when you type the letter "A", you can make it so that the numeric keys on your custom keyboard are disabled until the letter "C" is typed in. Keep in mind that this is easy to disable and enable, as the keys are buttons in the keyboard.

Comment: @ChristopherRicha yea thats a better idea, I will go with that if you say there is no other choice. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, both solutions provided by @Losiowaty and myself are legit, it really depends on the level of user experience you want to offer: if you don't really care about displaying keys as disabled on the keyboard, then the custom keyboard is overkill. Apple doesn't want you to go ahead and mess around with their keyboard, hence why they let us write our custom keyboards now 

Comment: @ChristopherRicha yea thats right :)

Answer (score 0):

As Losiowaty pointed this out in a comment, you should implement the delegate method of `UITextViewDelegate` called `shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:` and return `false`. That way, taps would be recognized by the keyboard but the buttons will be technically disabled.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    //other actions before returning, for e. g. informing the user that the keyboard is disabled

    return false
}
```